# Android app launch icon size

Tags: android, icons, size

Following Google's guidelines, I've added 48x48 and 72x72 launcher icons to my project for mdpi and hdpi screens.

In some situations though, the icon is resized. For example on my Acer Iconia A200 tablet (mdpi), the app launcher menu uses a 64x64 icon (more or less, I've measured this from a screenshot). The actual resource used is my 48x48 icon, stretched.

Is there a way I can add versions of the launcher icon to my project with more size options than hdpi/mdpi/ldpi?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Today's software update for the Acer Iconia Tab A200 fixed the problem for me; the launcher now uses a 72x72 icon.

Comment: You can try drawable-hdpi-v8, drawable-mdpi-v9, etc, or just look up the documentation for drawable folder.

Comment: [DeveloperSite](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size) will provide the details for you.

Comment: Thanks Demonick, that's interesting and I didn't know that yet. I don't think the image resizing behaviour is version-specific though?

Comment: Thanks SpK, I read the guide but it doesn't seem to answer my question?

Comment: Some up-to-date information about icon best practice: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/making-beautiful-android-app-icons.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xlarge qualifier though I doubt that the tablet is using size other than the 48x48, I am using the 48x48 icon and it is working fine on the Galaxy 10.1 tablet.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I should clarify a bit: the used icon is indeed the 48x48 one. It's scaled to 64x64 though in the app launcher menu and it could potentially be scaled to any size, like 36x36 in a context menu. My question is if I can add such different image sizes to my project?

Comment: Although it didn't quite solve my problem, I'll accept this answer because it's the only one and there don't seem be any new ones :) The help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Stuart same problem with Transformer Prime tablet with ICS. I made the icon source 64x64 for now, and it grew nicely in size, but i have not tested it on any other devices ...

Comment: @Cel I've not found a better solution either, but this shifts the problem to devices that do use the default size for icons. I see that other apps on my Acer Iconia A200 have incorrectly sized icons too, so I think this maybe shouldn't be solved by the individual apps but with a launcher update/replacement.