# Android app icon is always smaller than it should be

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have been trying for a long time to create an Android app icon that is the same size as all of the other icons on the device, but my icon is always too small.

I know this is a well documented problem. I have tried every solution I have found but my app icon is still too small.

The posts I have read on Stackoverflow include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980139/android-app-icon-size-too-small), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203862/android-app-launch-icon-size), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231439/app-icon-on-device-is-too-small) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788598/android-app-icon-small-size-issue).

I have used this tool: [Android asset studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher). It made the icon too small but that was a know issue. I forked the repo and implemented [this fix](https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio/issues/73) as documented, but still too small.

I have also tried [this tool](https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=E8EAF6%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&backColor=3F51B5%2C100&effects=none&elevate=0), [this tool](https://appicon.co/) and [this tool](https://appiconmaker.co/), but they all gave me an icon that showed up as too small on my device.

Then I discovered the tool in Android studio, [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio), but unfortunately the icons it produces are too small.

I have tried using a 512 x 512 file in every folder (hdpi / mdpi etc).

I have tried placing them in `drawable` instead of `mipmap`.

There is no padding in the source image, the icon reaches the edges of it and is a 512 x 512 png file. I use Android Studio Image Asset Studio to produce the correct sizes.

I place the 48 x 48 in mipmap-hdpi, 
I place the 72 x 72 in mipmap-mdpi, 
I place the 96 x 96 in mipmap-xhdpi,
I place the 144 x 144 in mipmap-xxhdpi,
I place the 192 x 192 in mipmap-xxxhdpi.

I have used various devices, virtual and physical.

Here are the specs of the source image:

[image]

Here is the shape of the source image for `ic_launcher_round`:

[image]

I am a Javascript developer using React Native so not very familiar with the Android ecosystem.

How do I make my icon the same size as all the other icons on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you put file in wrong folder.

The 48 x 48 file should in mipmap-mdpi

and

The 72 x 72 file should in mipmap-hdpi

```
Name           Density         Pixel
ldpi(0.75x)    120 dpi       36 x 36 px
mdpi(baseline) 160 dpi       48 x 48 px
hdpi (1.5x)    240 dpi       72 x 72 px
xhdpi (2x)     320 dpi       96 x 96 px
xxhdpi (3x)    480 dpi      144 x 144 px
xxxhdpi (4x)   640 dpi      192 x 192 px
```

[FYR](https://makeappicon.com/androidicon)

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, I'll try this out - I have one question which is that where is mentions 'dpi' in the link you gave, should I be changing the resolution of each file? I start with just a 72 dpi resolution.

Comment: It's the [pixel densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) , it will auto to find out what is the closer to catch the picture size. So you just put correct size in correct folder, it should be appear well.